# In PHP fetch content and truncate the string or variable, till 3rd breakline then display

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

//In PHP  fetch content and truncate the string or variable, till 3rd   breakline then display
//when i use this method the entire div deallocated and the its not  displaying properly...hope the fetch content contain some image tags too // ...

```
<div class="mid-blks-cont">
  <!-- Block1 -->
   <div class="mid-block-1 boxgrid caption">
   <?php             
     foreach ($querypost as $row) {
         $content = $row->post_content;
         $pcontent_overview = (strlen($content) > 300) ?  substr($content,0,300).'... <a href="#">Read More</a>' : $content;
         if($img == "No Image Uploaded" ) {
    ?>

    <img alt="" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/samples/sample1.jpg"style="width: 391px; height:231px"/>

    <?php } else { ?>

     <img alt="" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $row->post_media ;?>" style="width: 391px; height:231px" />

    <?php }?>

   <h4 class="cat-label cat-label2"><a href="<?php echo site_url('blog_panel/category1'); ?>"><?php echo $row->category;?></a></h4>

   <div class="cover boxcaption">
     <h3><a href="<?php echo site_url('blog_panel/post/'.$row->ID); ?>"><?php echo $row->post_title;?></a><span class="topic-icn"><?php echo $row->comment_count;?></span></h3>
     <p> <?php echo $pcontent_overview;?>....</p>
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('blog_panel/post/'.$row->ID); ?>">MORE <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Avoid to break your code in that way, it becomes very hard to debug. All the HTML elements can be created with an `echo`, all you have to do is to escape the double quotes adding a slash before them: `\"`.

Comment: I agree with Marco, and you might want to create an image helper function. This would give you two things: 1) one place to go and modify or debug 2) readability.